# How to answer these growth and coverage testing interview questions?

Tags: interview

I have two interview questions, please help me to research the best answer:

1. What are sources that you often use to consult and improve your testing knowledge?
2. How do you know that your test cases cover the requirements?

Comment: how are we supposed to know what sources you often use?

Answer (score 5):

These are common interview questions, and there are ways to answer them that will be helpful to you.

**Sources you often use to consult and improve your testing knowledge.**

Frankly, unless you read through any suggestions you get and keep going back, you will be cheating - and if the interviewer is familiar with a source you give that you're not familiar with, you will not only lose any change of working with that organization, you could find yourself on multiple people's "do not hire" lists because people will talk about someone who tries to cheat their way through an interview.

That said, some of the sites I find particularly helpful are:

- The [Ministry of Testing](http://www.ministryoftesting.com) and all their associated sites
- This site.
- [Alan Page's](http://angryweasel.com/blog/) blog.

**How do you know test cases cover the requirement**

You don't. You do your best to decompose the requirement into granular pieces of functionality and aim to test those. There's always the chance you'll miss something so you ask others to check your tests to see if there are any conditions you've missed. You discuss the requirement with others to look for implied functionality and assumptions that the author of the requirement may have been making. You look for prerequisites and incompatible functionality.

When you think you might have most of it, you look at the risks of each thing you've identified failing, and you test more or less in this order:

1. Must have (the requirement fails if it does not do these things)
2. Highest risk
3. Other tests from high-risk to low risk.

Comment: +1 for how easy is to find out that person cheated/faked the experience: just ask few open-ended questions. It is very sad when I had to cancel the interview because it was obvious that candidate cheated (and even worse, group lunch with candidate was cancelled too).

Comment: @PeterMasiar It's sad how many people seem to think it's a good idea to cheat their way through an interview, as if the skills they claim aren't going to be needed. I much prefer to claim only what I have, and if they're looking for more point out that I learn quickly - with examples of how I've picked up new skills in the past.

Comment: I've told people on the first interview that I didn't know the specific requirement asked for, but I do know something similar, and if they feel I am a good fit for the company, I would take the time before an in-person interview to educate myself on the specific differences. It showed both honesty and a willingness to work hard to be a better employee for the company's needs. In the end, I got the second interview, but declined the job based on my needs.

Comment: @MivaScott That is certainly a good way to answer questions like that - and yes, learning more about the company before you go in for the interview is a good technique as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best answers are the most honest one. In your case maybe even: 1. None, yet & 2. Don't know, but willing to learn.

My answers to these questions would be something in line of:

1. I use the following sources to stay up-to-date:

   - Researching and answering questions on [SQA.SE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)
   - Reading [developer](http://blog.cleancoder.com/) and industry blogs
   - Listing to [testing](http://www.angryweasel.com/ABTesting/) and [developer](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcasts/) podcasts on my commutes
2. Coverage is not the goal, I would even challenge if the requirements are right, as most customers change their mind when they see something for the first time. The team should balance the [Test-Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html), but I expect at least:

   - One happy path end-to-end test
   - One negative end-to-end test
   - 65-80% Unit- or Integration-test coverage (in order to adapt fast to the customers changing vision)
   - A time-boxed exploratory testing session to find gaps in the test automation